# Return an array in a specified order

Tags: graphql, bigcommerce

Currently, I'm trying to figure out a method to obtain the GraphQL result in the exact same order as an argument (array) passed to the query.

I do not have the argument available to me beforehand.

Suppose I have the following query:

```
query GetProducts($productIds: [Int!]) {
    products(entityIds: $productIds) {
       data
    }
}
```

I would like to obtain the result of `$productIds`, which isn't known or available to me prior to the query.
Desired result, simplified:

```
"data": {"id": 1...} {"id": 2...} {"id": 3...}
"argument": {"productIds": [3, 1, 2]}
```

Comment: Are you talking about on the server or the client? On the client you should know. On the server the array *should* be in your `args` for the resolver in the same order that it was provided in on the client.